# What is the best type of index to use on a materialized view in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to increase the performance of queries on table in  Postgrsql db i need to use.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    article_number text NOT NULL,
    description text NOT null,
    feature text NOT null,
    ...
);
```

The table is just in example but the thing is that there are no unique columns. `article_number` is the one used in the `where` clause but for example `article_number='000.002-00A'` can have from 3 to 300 rows. The total number of rows is 102,165,920. What would be the best index to use for such a situation?

I know there B-tree, Hash, GiST, SP-GiST, GIN and BRIN index types in postgres but which one would be the best for this.

Answer (score 1):

If the lookups are filtered on `article_number` then an index should be created on that. Not quite sure what else you're asking.

The default index is a btree and that'll work fine. If you're only checking for strict equality `hash` would also be an option but it has issues before Postgres 10, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Other index types are for more complicated forms of querying or custom data types, there's no reason to even consider them if you just want to perform equality filters.

- btrees are useful for strict equality and range searches (which includes prefix search e.g. `foo like 'bar%'`)
- hash indexes are useful only for strict equality they can be faster & smaller than btrees in some rare cases
- GIN indexes are useful when you have multiple index values per row (arrays, json, gis, some FTS cases)
- GiST indexes are useful for more complex querying than equality and range (geom/gis, FTS)

I've never looked into BRIN index so I'm not sure what their use case would be. But my understanding is that there's no case to even consider it before you have huge numbers of rows.

Basically, use btree unless you *know* that you can not.

Comment: Im asking what kind of index should it be. btree, GiST, GIN or any other

Comment: I edited my answer to match. btree is what you should use. In pg > 10 hash *could* also be an option but it would require benchmarking to make sure.